# Is it possible to create a Google Play Family group using a Google Gift Card?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-family

When attempting to create a Google Play Family group, Google asks for credit card information.

Is it possible to create a Google Play Family group using a Google Play Gift Card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not possible**

From Google support [Google Family plan Without Credit Card?](https://support.google.com/googleplay/forum/AAAA8CVOtD8uAeAleYEzFs)

> Currently, you HAVE to have a credit card on file to use as the Family Payment method.  Even if everyone in the Family then uses their own payment method or the credits redeemed to their own accounts instead.

IMO, it sounds logical - a credit card establishes owner traceability and prevents two family accounts being operated by same person (which is not permitted - see [family group requirements](https://support.google.com/families/answer/7251139?hl=en)
) whereas a gift card doesn't

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, why does Google need "owner traceability", given that having sufficient funds should be all that matters?  Also, could a pre-paid credit card be used?

Comment: I really can't answer why it needs but going by a) normal business modus operandi b) you cannot be a part of two family accounts as I understand , so that may be a check that you don't use the same credit card again. Regarding pre paid I have no idea. All this is from Internet. Family accounts are not permitted in my country so can't say for sure

Comment: Possibly pre paid CC can be set up as a family payment method to restrict purchases

Comment: Welcome. Updated answer including aspect of one person not being a part of two family accounts

Comment: "Owner traceability" is a key factor to determining that the locale of the transaction is never associated with an account holder in export-restricted countries. There was a question related to financial transactions from Myannmar (Burma), which is on the restricted list, on this stackexchange just within this past week. Gift cards are transient, so there is zero assurance of this.

Comment: Also owner traceability is important because family group is not available on all locations. I could use a VPN and pretend to be in USA and use International CC

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when my son got a Google play card for his birthday. It wouldn't allow him to add the balance to his account, only mine. So I did. And then I couldn't set the family payment method to anything but our credit card. I FINALLY figured out how to use his credit. He wanted Minecraft which I think is about 10 bucks. So I downloaded it to my phone, paid with the play card balance,  and added the game to our family library. Then I downloaded it on his phone with no extra charge. I just disabled the app on my own phone afterward. Now if he wants to spend credit, I download what he wants, use his play card credit, then he can get the same app on his phone.

Comment: *"added the game to our family library"* - and how do you create that family library (w/o cc) in the first place? That's what OP asked.